# Binding an Image control to a datagrids datacontext (viewmodel)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selecteditem, collectionviewsource

I have a WPF `DataGrid` that is bound to a `CollectionViewSource`. The view source contains some data about rental properties, i.e. the address and an image of that property. The `DataGrid` shows the address information but the image is shown via an `Image` control outside of the `DataGrid`. This `Image` control is bound to the data same `DataContext` as the `DataGrid`. The idea is that when the user selects a row in the `DataGrid` the image changes to the image of that property. Select a different row (property) and the image changes (I have put the `Image` control outside of the `DataGrid` as showing every image make the grid rather large). By default the `DataGrid` is read only with a row selection unit of 'fullrow'. So far all works as required. I have a `Button` to allow the user to edit the grid, this changes the grid to editable with a row selection unit of 'cell'.

Now it falls over, the image disappears and there no longer seems to be a link back to the `DataContext`. I am guessing that some magic is linking the selected item of the data grid back to the view source which allows the image property to be available to my `Image` control but once the row selection changes to cell there is no longer a selected item in the `DataGrid`.

How do I keep the image visible when I make the grid editable?

I am not a professional programmer and am learning WPF and C# for 'fun'.
Grateful thanks.

The relevant markup for the `DataGrid`:

```xml
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Entities="clr-namespace:wpfPortfolioManager.Entities"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfPortfolioManager"
    xmlns:DataSets="clr-namespace:wpfPortfolioManager.DataSets"
    xmlns:dsAllTablesTableAdapters="clr-namespace:wpfPortfolioManager.DataSets.dsAllTablesTableAdapters" x:Name="window" x:Class="wpfPortfolioManager.Forms.HomeScreen"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="HomeScreen" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="propertyViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Entities:Property}, CreateList=True}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TabItem x:Name="tabProperties" Header="Properties" DataContext="{StaticResource propertyViewSource}" Background="{x:Null}" >
        <Grid Background="#FFDA4D2E" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="98"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Width="{Binding ElementName=buttonSaveProperties, Path=Width}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="78">
                <Button x:Name="buttonSaveProperties" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=propertyDataGrid, Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource convertBoolean}}" Click="buttonSaveProperties_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="90">
                        <Image   Stretch="Fill" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0" Source="Save_16x.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>

                <Button  x:Name="buttonCancel" Margin="2,5" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=propertyDataGrid, Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource convertBoolean}}" Click="buttonCancelProperty_Click">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="90">
                        <Image   Stretch="Fill" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0" Source="stop.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                <Button x:Name="buttonMakeEditable" Click="buttonMakePropertiesEditable_Click"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="30" Height="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <Image Source="i_edit-itemBlue_F12.png"  Stretch="Fill" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="1"/>
                </Button>
                <DataGrid x:Name="propertyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty}" Style="{DynamicResource ReadOnlyDataGridStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" RowHeaderWidth="20">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="propertyNameColumn" Width="Auto" Header="Property" Binding="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address1Column" Width="Auto" Header="Street" Binding="{Binding Address1}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address2Column" Width="Auto" Header="Town" Binding="{Binding Address2}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address3Column" Width="Auto" Header="County" Binding="{Binding Address3}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address4Column" Width="Auto" Header="Post Code" Binding="{Binding Address4}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="columnNewPicture" Header="New Picture"  Visibility="Collapsed" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button x:Name="buttonNewPicture" Click="buttonNewPicture_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PropertyID}" Height="10" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=propertyDataGrid, Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource convertBoolean}}"></Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF6EA410" BorderThickness="2" Height="150" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <Image x:Name="testImage" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="150"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>

<!-- Rest of the xaml file -->

</Window>
```

`DataGrid` style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="BaseDataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">

    <!--#region Grid -->
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Font -->
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Height & Width -->
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50 "/>
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="800"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="600"/>-->
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1200"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Columns -->
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeader}"/>
    <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Rows -->
    <!--<Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Red"/>-->
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridCellText}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--<Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ReadOnlyDataGridStyle"  BasedOn="{StaticResource  BaseDataGridStyle}" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <!--#region Grid -->

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Rows -->
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

</Style>

<Style x:Key="EditableDataGridStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource  BaseDataGridStyle}" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <!--#region Grid -->
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="Cell"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Rows -->
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="True"/>
    <!--#endregion-->
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeader" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <!--#region Column Header -->
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <!--#endregion-->
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridCellText" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <!--#region Cell -->
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5, 5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40"/>
    <!--#endregion-->
</Style>
```

`DataContext` is set as:

```cs
private void InitialiseDataContext()
{
    CollectionViewSource propertyViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("propertyViewSource")));
    CollectionViewSource tenantViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("tenantViewSource")));

    _context.Properties.Load();
    _context.Tenants.Load();

    propertyViewSource.Source = _context.Properties.Local;
    tenantViewSource.Source = _context.Tenants.Local;
}
```

`DataGrid` is made editable by this code:

```cs
dgEditable = (Style)FindResource("EditableDataGridStyle");
dgReadonly = (Style)FindResource("ReadOnlyDataGridStyle");

private void buttonMakePropertiesEditable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    propertyDataGrid.Style = propertyDataGrid.Style == dgEditable ? dgReadonly : dgEditable;
    foreach (var item in propertyDataGrid.Columns)
    {
        if (item.Header.ToString() == "New Picture")
        {
            item.Visibility = item.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems reasonable, even if you didn't show some things, like to what the `Image` control is binding to.

Anyway i found out that there is an issue with the `SelectionUnit = Cell`, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9489041/12730306).

The solution can be one of that or you can change your code to only use `SelectionUnit = FullRow`.

I don't know why you need `Cell` as `SelectionUnit` but if the main concern was to edit a single cell, you can still do it in `FullRow`.

This way you wouldn't have to do some fancy code to workaround this issue.

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: Hi Federico, thanks for quick answer. Yes selection unit = single cell was simply to allow editing, I didn't realise you could select a single cell in FullRow mode, I assumed doing so would take you out of FullRow  mode. Lots to learn! Many thanks